# Display database content in 3 blocks

Tags: php, html, css, html-table

I am using a table to display information from my database but I'm having trouble formatting the CSS. Right now I have 12 icons and the respective name on the right and the problem is that everything is displayed like a list, one below the other and I wanted to break the list in three blocks, like this:

[image: Image of desired outcome]

**EDIT** I don't need necessarily to do it with tables, I just need to display the values like this, dynamically. Because later I'd probably going to add more plants to database and I want them to be always listed like this.

**This is my html:**

```
<table id="plantslist"> 

<?php
foreach($resultado as $planta){ ?>

    <tr>
    <td><img src="http://www.coisas.pt/coisas/backoffice/<?php echo $planta['icon']; ?>"></img></td>

    <td><a href="blabla.php?name=<?php echo $planta['name']?>&img=<?php echo $planta['img']?>&tagline=<?php echo $planta['tagline']?>&hum=<?php echo $planta['hum']?>&lum=<?php echo $planta['lum']?>&temp=<?php echo $planta['temp']?>&seed=<?php echo $planta['seed']?>&spacing=<?php echo $planta['spacing']?>&info1=<?php echo $planta['info1']?>&info2=<?php echo $planta['info2']?>&info3=<?php echo $planta['info3']?>&info4=<?php echo $planta['info4']?>">
        <?php echo $planta['name'];?></a></td>

    </tr>

<?php   } ?>

</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
#plantslist {
    border: 3px solid white;
    overflow: scroll;
    font-size: 1.7vw;
    line-height: 2.8vw;
    font-family: Robotomedium;
    margin-top: 11%;
    text-align: left;

}

#plantslist img {width: 2.3vw;}

#plantslist tr td {

    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: You can do a conditional to detect multiples of 3; also you can set height and apply float:left to td's; another way is using nth-child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a container with `width: 100%`; then make child elements with `width: 33%` each one. To make them place one next to other you can use `float: left;`. Here is an example.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url(http://placehold.it/20/000) no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="items">1</div>
  <div class="items">2</div>
  <div class="items">3</div>
  <div class="items">4</div>
  <div class="items">5</div>
  <div class="items">6</div>
  <div class="items">7</div>
  <div class="items">8</div>
  <div class="items">9</div>
</div>
```

Look that your icon it's placed with before pseudo element. You should change `background` value with the correct url.

**EDIT**

Use this if you have different images per plant.

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/dfa9a9" alt=""> 1
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/dfa9de" alt=""> 2
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/b1a9df" alt=""> 3
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/a9cadf" alt=""> 4
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/dfd8a9" alt=""> 5
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/5cff46" alt=""> 6
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/dfa9a9" alt=""> 7
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/a9cadf" alt=""> 8
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/20/a9cadf" alt=""> 9
  </div>
</div>
```

### Using your PHP code

**HTML | PHP**

```
<div class="table">
<?php

    foreach($resultado as $planta){
        ?>

        <div class="items">
            <img src="http://www.growbox.pt/growbox/backoffice/<?php echo $planta['icon']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $planta['name'];?>">
            <a href="intips.php?name=<?php echo $planta['name']?>&img=<?php echo $planta['img']?>&tagline=<?php echo $planta['tagline']?>&hum=<?php echo $planta['hum']?>&lum=<?php echo $planta['lum']?>&temp=<?php echo $planta['temp']?>&seed=<?php echo $planta['seed']?>&spacing=<?php echo $planta['spacing']?>&info1=<?php echo $planta['info1']?>&info2=<?php echo $planta['info2']?>&info3=<?php echo $planta['info3']?>&info4=<?php echo $planta['info4']?>"><?php echo $planta['name'];?>
            </a>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.table > .items img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: this actually kinda works but the problem is that if i wanted to add more plants to my database, like, that's say, more 30 plants, i would have to go to my html page and change add a lot. And i want this to be more dynamic. Not sure if made myself clear. Can you help me? Thank you

Comment: But that's dynamic, You don't have to go to your HTML (static) page to add more plants. Did you saw the HTML / PHP code? Read all the answer.

Comment: oh forget, my bad, i was doing something wrong. thank you so much, it's exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works. I'm just creating more  elements so that you have 3 sets of tds per row. Ideally, though, I wouldn't do this with tables. I'd do something like arglab suggested with divs, but here I'm just showing you how I'd do it with tables since that was your question. Make your divs inline blocks with width 33% and you should be good. You may also need to do `box-sizing: border-box` so that way any padding and margins get automatically put into the calculation for you.

```
<table id="plantslist"> 

    <?php $count = 0; ?>

       <tr>

        <?php foreach($resultado as $planta) { 
            if (count === 2) {
                count = 0; ?>

              <td><img src="http://www.growbox.pt/growbox/backoffice/<?php echo              $planta['icon']; ?>"></img></td>

             <td><a href="intips.php?name=<?php echo $planta['name']?>&img=<?php echo $planta['img']?>&tagline=<?php echo $planta['tagline']?>&hum=<?php echo $planta['hum']?>&lum=<?php echo $planta['lum']?>&temp=<?php echo $planta['temp']?>&seed=<?php echo $planta['seed']?>&spacing=<?php echo $planta['spacing']?>&info1=<?php echo $planta['info1']?>&info2=<?php echo $planta['info2']?>&info3=<?php echo $planta['info3']?>&info4=<?php echo $planta['info4']?>">
            <?php echo $planta['name'];?></a></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

    <?php   }
    else {
        $count += 1;
        // If this doesn't work, try $count = $count + 1;

        <td><img src="http://www.growbox.pt/growbox/backoffice/<?php echo           $planta['icon']; ?>"></img></td>

        <td><a href="intips.php?name=<?php echo $planta['name']?>&img=<?php echo $planta['img']?>&tagline=<?php echo $planta['tagline']?>&hum=<?php echo $planta['hum']?>&lum=<?php echo $planta['lum']?>&temp=<?php echo $planta['temp']?>&seed=<?php echo $planta['seed']?>&spacing=<?php echo $planta['spacing']?>&info1=<?php echo $planta['info1']?>&info2=<?php echo $planta['info2']?>&info3=<?php echo $planta['info3']?>&info4=<?php echo $planta['info4']?>">

}

 ?>

    </table>
```

SOLUTION WITH DIVS: See if this works...

```
<div id="plantslist"> 
<?php foreach($resultado as $planta) { ?>
    <div class="plant">
        <img src="http://www.growbox.pt/growbox/backoffice/<?php echo $planta['icon']; ?>"></img>
        <a href="intips.php?name=<?php echo $planta['name']?>&img=<?php echo $planta['img']?>&tagline=<?php echo $planta['tagline']?>&hum=<?php echo $planta['hum']?>&lum=<?php echo $planta['lum']?>&temp=<?php echo $planta['temp']?>&seed=<?php echo $planta['seed']?>&spacing=<?php echo $planta['spacing']?>&info1=<?php echo $planta['info1']?>&info2=<?php echo $planta['info2']?>&info3=<?php echo $planta['info3']?>&info4=<?php echo $planta['info4']?>">
        <?php echo $planta['name'];?></a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#planstslist{
    width: 100%;

    /* this may help if the items don't stack properly */
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.plant{
    width: 33.33%
    display: inline-block;
    /* this may help if the items don't stack properly */
    white-space: normal;
}
```

You may need to make the images inline blocks and set them and the links to have percentage width values adding up to no more than 100%. You may also need to add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the "plant" divs. I usually get in the habit of making the following declaration on all my CSS files: `* {box-sizing: border-box};`

Comment: this gives me an syntax error with in **count++;**. Anyway this doesn't necessarily has to be made with tables, i just though it will be easier because all the php data. If you know another way to do it i'll be very thankful

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer. Let me know if it works : )

Answer (score 0):

I think it's enough if you simply erase `display: inline-block;` from this CSS rule;

```
#plantslist tr td {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

`display`should be `table-cell`, not `inline-block`, which is the default anyway in a `<td>` element. Also `vertical-align: top;` wouldn't be necessary, so you might as well erase the whole rule...